# How does magento2 create background administrators

Tags: magento2

The group leader gave me an installed magento2 and told me that I could create an administrator by myself. I am a novice, how should I operate? Thank you

Comment: you can learn create admin user by this link: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-new-admin-user-magento-2.html#step-1-configure-user-information